# Is a "const member function" checked at compile time or runtime?

Tags: c++

I am wondering when the checking for a `const` member function happens? I guess it happens at compile time, but cannot be sure.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

It happens at compile time. In C++ almost all the type checking is done at compile time. The only exception to this is when you use `dynamic_cast`.

So your `const` member function is checked at compile time.

Comment: `catch` is another "exception" (ha ha) where types are checked at runtime. The exception thrown (whose type is the static type of the throw expression) is compared with whatever catch clauses are on the call stack at the time. In general this cannot be known until runtime, for example call something through a function pointer, which calls through another function pointer into the code that throws, and that middle thing on the stack could be any function in the program with the right signature. Can't be statically analysed.

Comment: In some sense virtual methods could be considered to be a runtime type check (especially pointer-to-member calls to virtual functions with virtual base classes).

Comment: O'Boy the pedantic police got here first.

Answer (score 0):

A `const` member function is checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

`const`ness of member functions affects the type of the `this` pointer.  Type safety is checked at compile time (unless bypassed with a cast, most casts bypass safety checks, `dynamic_cast` adds a runtime check).

However, on most architectures `const`ness is not merely a type check, but enforced by the memory protection unit.  This happens at runtime, and is NOT bypassed by `const_cast` (or C-style cast).

Comment: I find that hard to believe; most const objects aren't const all of the time, and therefore need to live in writable memory.

Comment: @Neil: I think you mean a const pointer to a non-const object?  const objects are always const, `const_cast` can't take off `const` that was applied at the time of construction.

Comment: `const` usually isn't enforced by the MMU for types with complex constructors, i.e. those ctors who can't be reduced to compile time operations.

Comment: @MSalters: We're looking at two different sides of the same thing.  MPU checks are not guaranteed to occur, but they are allowed to.  Just because code compiled does not mean it will not fail at runtime due to an access violation detected by the MPU.

Comment: @Ben Voight: obviously, for incorrect code (with Undefined Behavior). But if standards compliant code is compiled, the compiler may not use instructions that would cause an MPU check to fail. Constructors do run for `const` objects and are allowed to modify the members (the `this` pointer isn't `const` yet), so that's a special case of standards-complaint code where the MPU must allow the operation.

Comment: @MSalters: True, but the compiler can also determine that the constructor has no external side-effects, and simply store the result into the constant data segment.  Or it could cause the memory to become protected after the constructor finishes.  Point is, const checking is not compile-only, where it can be turned off by `const_cast`.  There can be runtime enforcement.

Comment: Right, but that's what I was trying to get out of by describing it as "most" - you can find examples of objects that will be put into read-only pages but most objects aren't declared globally and therefore don't even qualify at the first hurdle.

Comment: @Neil, @MSalters: In summary: Is ALL `const` enforced at runtime? No.  Is ANY `const` enforced at runtime? Yes.